# web3@1.0.0-beta.55 would not properly installed on mac

Tags: python, anaconda, ethereum, truffle, web3py

I am setting up my own start-kit which does not rely on Truffle to build some ethereum blockchain app.Then, I npm init and attempted to install web3@1.0.0-beta.55 and npm install solc my console shows an error.

Is this affected by anaconda and python?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below suggested steps

1. Install NodeJS using NVM(Node Version Manager). Check this https://www.chrisjmendez.com/2018/02/07/install/
2. brew install postgresql   - Install libpq-dev
3. Try to install web3 this version >>> 1.0.0-beta.33

and it should work